# Python Order When Setting Multiple Variables

Tags: python

I'm working in python and came across this line of code:

```
a, c = c, getMod(a,c)
```

I am trying to translate this program into TI-84 language, and I don't know how to do it. Is there a specific order they go in, or is it more complicated than that?

getMod() is a function I set up, and is not important in this scenario. It returns a%c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as [tuple unpacking](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Tuples#Packing_and_Unpacking).  Essentially, the order in which the variables are identified is the order in which they are assigned.

That line of code is semantically equal to:

```
a = c
c = getMod(a, c)
```

Comment: That's not right.  Consider `getMod = lambda x,y: x*y`.  Then `a,c=2,3; a = c; c = getMod(a,c)` results in `a,c = 3,9`, but the one-liner using unpacking gives `a,c = 3,6`.  More simply, think of `x,y = y,x`-- if you were right, that wouldn't work..

Comment: OK, thank you. For future reference, in that line, when a used in getMod() it has the same value as it did before the line a = c. That is the only difference between the two

Comment: You'd need to use an additional temporary variable to get the equivalent result in a language that doesn't support tuple assignment.